# How to setup the tool in windows 10?

Tags: neutrinos-platform

I have tried installing **Neutrinos Studio** in Windows 10 OS but I am getting an error, what is the minimum requirements to install the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the requirement

- 8GB RAM or above
- Dual Core Processor or above
- 200 GB Hard disk space or above